# Jenkins pipeline: How to get the hostname of an agent

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-agent

I have two different Linux servers (prod and dev) with different `$HOSTNAME` and different certificates, which are by default named after the hostname.

Now I want to determine within the Jenkins-Pipeline on which host I am and thus use the correct certificate.

To do so I wrote the following test script:

```
def labels = []
labels.add('jenkins_<agenthost>_x86')
def builders = [:]

for (x in labels) {
    def label = x
    builders[label] = {
        ansiColor('xterm') {
            node (label) {
                stage('cleanup') {
                    deleteDir()
                }
                stage('test') {
                    sh """
                        echo $HOSTNAME
                    """
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

parallel builders
```

Which does not work since the `$HOSTNAME` is not defined.

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: HOSTNAME for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

How can I get the hostname of the jenkins-agent within a `sh` in a pipeline?

---

Since you can name the node in any way you like, you can't just use the `NODE_NAME`, it does not have to be the same as the `$HOSTNAME` you would get from echo `$HOSTNAME` on a bash on the agent machine.

Comment: `HOSTNAME` needs to be defined.

Comment: Yeah, how do I define it?

Comment: `NODE_NAME` in the `env` object can assist greatly here.

Answer (score 1):

```
def getJenkinsMaster() {
    return env.BUILD_URL.split('/')[2].split(':')[0]
}
```

You can get the hostname from the url

Comment: That's cool, but I'm looking for the host name of the slave, not the master

Answer (score 0):

```
sh "echo ${env.NODE_NAME}"
```

You can add this shell command and get the hostname from the environment variable.

Comment: The `NODE_NAME` does not have to contain the actual `HOSTNAME` like you would get it from `echo $HOSTNAME` on a bash on the slave.

Answer (score 0):

not sh step, but you can use groovy:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread
import hudson.FilePath

@NonCPS
def get_current_pipeline_node() {
    def thread = CpsThread.current()
    def cv = thread.contextVariables
    def fp
    try {
        fp = cv.get(FilePath, null, null)
    } catch(MissingMethodException) {
        fp = cv.get(FilePath)
    }
    return fp?.toComputer()?.node
}
node = get_current_pipeline_node()
print(node.nodeName)
```